# they stole my truck

Tags: meaning, pronouns

a. They stole my truck last week.

Could one use that sentence if one has no idea who stole the truck, whether there was one thief or more involved, etc. ?

All one knows is that one's truck was stolen. Maybe one person did it, maybe more. One doesn't have an inkling who the thieves were.

Obviously, the sentence is correct if one knows who 'they' are. But I wondered if you found 'they' natural when one has no idea of 'their' identity.

Comment: This is not about English. Can't you that in your native tongue??

Answer (score 2):

Pronouns normally need an antecedent (exceptions are things like dummy pronouns and not really relevant here).  The context needs to supply the antecedent, which could be vague and not specify the actual identity.

> There are lots of thieves in this town.  I think they stole my truck.

Here "they" refers to "thieves", but the speaker doesn't know who.

You can use "they" when the identity and gender is unknown.

> I heard footsteps outside the door. I couldn't tell if there was one person or many, but I think they stole my truck.

Or you could point at someone (who you can't identify as male or female) and say "I think they stole my truck".  Here the antecedent is provided by the gesture (This is an example of *exophora*).

On the other hand it would not be correct to say to a police officer with no other context

> Excuse me, Officer.  I think they stole my truck.

Because nothing in this exchange provides for an antecedent.

Instead you might say "I think someone stole my truck" or "I think my truck has been stolen."

---

An interesting exception mentioned in comments is when a pronoun is modified by a relative clause.  This can have generic sense

> They who stole my truck must be around here.

In this use it is fairly formal.  The use of "they" here suggests that the speaker doesn't know identity, gender and even number. The speaker believes that there are several people it would be possible for the speaker to be mistaken.

Comment: Pronouns don't need an antecedent. For example "You smelll" or "It doesn't matter" or "You don't need to be rich to get into Harvard" or "They've arrested my wife!" or "One never knows" or "He who lives by the sword dies by the sword" or "Who stole my bicycle?" or ""What's been eating my lettuce?"  or "We are not amused" etc, etc

Comment: While not all pronouns need a referent, the third-person pronouns “he”, “she” and “they” _do_, except in a small number of cases.  In the “arrested my wife” example, you are very clearly missing a referent, because the immediate response to such a statement would be: “who did?” (The Carabinieri? The Sheriff? The City Police? Customs and Border Patrol?).  The other examples you give are idiomatic uses where “he” and “you” are used in place of the pronoun “one”, and that substitution is acceptable only in some phrases: e.g., compare “one never knows...” with “she never knows...”

Comment: Iv'e qualified my sweeping generalisation.  The reference of a profound can be an endophora (referring to something in the text), or an exophora. In "You smell" the reference is an exophora, referring to the second person in the conversation.   There are some cases, like "it doesn't matter" in which the pronoun is a dummy, but that doesn't apply here.  Similarly, interrogatives are not really relevant to this question.  The only interesting example is "He who lives by the sword".  There is a use of  "They" when qualified by a relative cluase "They who stole my car are nearby!"

Comment: @JamesK Yes, most pronouns need a referent. Sure. But not an *antecedent*. Those exophoric pronouns have referents but they  don't have any antecedents. And the most common personal pronouns are normally used without any antecedents: *I, you, we.*

Answer (score 2):

This would be a perfectly correct use of the "singular they". It is most often used where one does not know or is unsure of the gender of the person one is referring to. So "he" or "she" are not possible.

But it is also perfectly valid if one does not know the number ie. whether there was one or more than one.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's perfectly all right to use "they" for one or more completely unknown agents, you might prefer the "I had my car stolen"  alternative.